# Flash source code pull down AS3 actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there any way to pull down the source code for a page using actionscript 3?

For example, it goes to google.com and downloads the source code for it, then stores it in an array or string.  Would URLdownloader work?

How could one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a URLRequest

```
function getContent():void 
    {
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://example.com');
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, contentLoaded);
        loader.load(request);           
    }
function contentLoaded(e:Event):void 
    {
        //html stored in target.data
        trace(e.currentTarget.data);
    }
```

Comment: keep in mind that this *won't* work online due to security sandboxing. you will need to use a proxy script on your server to fetch the html.

Comment: ...or build an AIR application, which isn't limited to this security sandbox.